# Buttons are cropped

Tags: android, xml, button

I have this layout, and when they're becoming visible, the go and again buttons are being cropped on some devices, so you can only see half of them.
any idea why?
Could it possibly be the margins? How do I fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_camera"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clipChildren="false" >



<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_alignEnd="@id/camera_preview"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:clipChildren="false" />
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/head"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/square" />
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/body"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/square" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/stop"
  android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:layout_width="40dp" />

 <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/takePic"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/go"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@id/camera_preview"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
      android:layout_margin="20dp"
      android:clickable="false"
      android:text="Go!"
      android:visibility="invisible" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/again"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_margin="20dp"
       android:clickable="false"
       android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
       android:text="Again"
       android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks!

Comment: Posting a picture may help.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it might be the margins : I guess the devices where this code doesn't work are the smallest or these with the lowest resolution. To solve your problem, I'd propose that you create a dimens.xml file in your res folder and you call it value-??dpi (depends on which resolution you have problem with). Here is an example :

My Layout file (res/layout/mylayout)

```
<LinearLayout
android:height="@dimen/heightmylayout"
android:width="@dimen/widthmylayout"
android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

My Dimens files : as many as you want ; here one for mdpi and one for hdpi:

HDPI (res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml) :

```
<resources>
<dimen name="heightmylayout">160dp</dimen>
<dimen name="widthmylayout">160dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

MDPI (res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml) :

```
<resources>
<dimen name="heightmylayout">110dp</dimen>
<dimen name="widthmylayout">110dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

With that, the emulators and phones will see which dimens they must take.

Hope it helps !